# How to get the source of the ActionEvent in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I'm trying to make a slide puzzle on java. Now I have a little problem. I want to know the index of a button I clicked, that sits in an `ArrayList`.

The `ArrayList<JButton>` buttons, contains a number of `JButton`s, I added an ActionListener to each button before putting it into this `ArrayList`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some code as a reference:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (buttons.contains(ae.getSource()) == true)
    {
        int click = buttons.indexOf(ae.getSource()); // <--- What's wrong with this?

        System.out.println(click);  /* I checked the index I got by printing 
                                       it out as a test, and it always gives 
                                       me the Integer '0', even if I clicked 
                                       the 9th Button for example. */
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No click");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is set a client property on each button:

```
JButton one = new JButton("1");
one.putClientProperty("Which", new Integer(1));
```

Then in the action listener user:

```
JButton button = ae.getSource();
int value = button.getClientProperty("Which").intValue();
```

You'll have to add some casts and some error checking but that's the gist of it ...